# How To Install Powertop 2.3 & Permanently Save Changed Of Powertop Suggestions In Ubuntu?

Tags: compiling, battery, powertop

I have Google every ppa and checked that they all have the powertop 2.1, So how can i install powertop 2.3 just recently released.

How do make permanently save changes of powertop, i know i can put all the output of powertop in **rc.local** but after plugin ac power and plugged out ac power all changes are **lost**, because all changes are made on boot not on " ac plugin and ac plug-out ", so i want to only powertop  commands to work if i my on battery ( ac plugged out ) and when i plugged in ac power i want performance, i don't want to save battery as i m on ac power.